# Unable to extract 4 bytes from a 8 byte scalar value - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, cgrect

I use this following swift code to get the keyboard height

```
let keyboardSize:CGRect? = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize!.height
```

When i print the description of "keyboardHeight" in log it says,

[image]

How to get the keyboard height here

EDIT: My entire objective is to move the view while show/hide keyboard only if it necessary. This is the full method i used for this purpose. What is the cause for the error in this.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification)
{
    let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize!.size.height

    let windowHeight = self.view.frame.size.height
    let keyboardStartPoint = windowHeight - keyboardHeight

    let textFieldFrame: CGRect! = activeTextField.convert(activeTextField.bounds, to: nil)
    let textFieldEndPoint = textFieldFrame.origin.y + textFieldFrame.height

    if (textFieldEndPoint > keyboardStartPoint)
    {
        movedDistance = textFieldEndPoint - keyboardStartPoint
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= movedDistance
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running you code on iPhone/iPad or on you Mac? Can you specify your device arch?

Comment: It worked fine in the Simulator in my MAC. But this problem occurred in my iPad (OS - 9.3.5)

Comment: Perhaps it is only a debugger problem. Does `print(keyboardHeight)` work correctly?

Comment: @Mano, oh ok, `CGFloat` on 32 bit systems(like your iPad) is `typealias` to `Float` which is 32bit long (4 byte), and on 64 bit (like your Mac) is `typealias` to `Double` which is 64 bit long (8 byte). Hence error in the title. It looks like for some reason `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` always contain NSValue with `CGRect` defined over 64bit `CGFloat`.